# Which element is equivalent to Android ListView on iOS?

Tags: swift, xcode

I have this screen below on Android

[image: Text]

It's a list with many elements

I need to implement it on iOS, but I have no idea what element I should use it on Xcode.
What I should use:

- StackView with horizontal layout
- UItableView
- UICollectionView
- basic UIView with another elements inside
- Another element?

What element is most recommended to create the list

Comment: If the data is fixed, you should go with stack view/basic uiview. But if the data is dynamic, you should use table views or collection views. This is for UIKit - if you're using SwiftUI, there are things like List and LazyVStack

Comment: My data is dynamic. I'm not using SwiftUI, I use Storyboard.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A UITableView is probably the quickest/easiest to setup for a simple list.

Since iOS 14, you have also been able to create a list using a UICollectionView too.

Comment: Couldn't you also make this type of layout with UICollectionView before iOS 14?

Comment: It's possible but previously collection views were used for cells that don't take up the whole width of the screen like a UITableView does.

Comment: I need an element that takes the entire width of the screen. I will try to use a UITableView because it appears that is a very common element used in Xcode.